# Problem with \lstinline in the caption of lstlisting environment

Tags: listings

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray},  
    emph={FMD},
    emphstyle={\color{orange}},
    emph={[2]RAW},
    emphstyle={[2]\color{blue}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Caption with {\lstinline[emphstyle=\ttfamily,basicstyle=\ttfamily]+FMD+} and {\lstinline[emphstyle=\ttfamily,basicstyle=\ttfamily]+RAW+}}]
This line inclues FMD and RAW.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

How can highlighting be disabled in the caption when there are more than one level of emphstyle?

Comment: Could you extend your code fragment into a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please? It helps troubleshooting possible solutions etc

Comment: @JamesT, please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray},  
    emph={FMD},
    emphstyle={\color{orange}},
    emph={[2]RAW},
    emphstyle={[2]\color{blue}}
}

\newcommand{\inline}[1]{\lstinline[emphstyle={\ttfamily},emphstyle={[2]\ttfamily},basicstyle=\ttfamily][#1[}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Caption with \inline{FMD} and \inline{RAW}}]
This line inclues FMD and RAW.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And why you do not use simply `\texttt{...}`??

Comment: @user187802, Thanks for your answer. I voted it up. I'm not a TeX expert. I don't know the differences between these commands very well. One thing in your answer that annoys me is that words containing characters such as underscore (_) must be first manipulated so that they are shown correctly with `\ttfamily`. I also don't know if `\ttfamily` uses the same font as `lstlisting` does.

Comment: that is a simple `\_`. It was you who said that `\ttfamily` should be used by `\lstinline`. See your definition ...

Answer (score 4):

Using `\lstinline` in the caption makes no sense here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray},  
    emph={FMD},
    emphstyle={\color{orange}},
    emph={[2]RAW},
    emphstyle={[2]\color{blue}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Caption with {\ttfamily FMD} and {\ttfamily RAW}}]
This line inclues FMD and RAW.
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Caption with {\lstinline[emphstyle=\ttfamily,basicstyle=\ttfamily]+FMD+} and {\lstinline[emphstyle=\ttfamily,basicstyle=\ttfamily]+RAW+}}]
This line inclues FMD and RAW.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]